# Task causing issues while testing

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I currently have a `Supervisor` that's supervising some `Task`'s. The task is responsible for asynchronously sending an email and updating the database. I'm testing a function which will start these tasks although the task is irrelevant to the test.

When I run the test I see `Ecto.StaleEntryError`'s printed in STDOUT. I believe this is happening because Ecto will delete the record after the test has finished but before the task has run. When it tries to update the record it doesn't exist and therefore an `Ecto.StaleEntryError` occurs.

As a side note, the test doesn't fail. It only prints a stack trace.

I'm not sure if I should try and prevent the task from executing somehow or if there's another approach.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with your supervisor.  Are you just trying to test a single supervisor function without actually starting the supervisor?

Comment: I'd like to prevent the task from executing as it's irrelevant to my test and is throwing stack traces in my test output. I figured the approach would be to prevent the supervisor from running so the task doesn't execute. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach and if it is I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the [`explicit contract`](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/).

Make your `Supervisor` to use different `Task` implementation, reading from config:

```
@task Application.get_env(:my_app, :task_impl)
```

and execute `@task.async` instead of `Task.async`. Also, make `config/proc.exs` to declare the proper implementation:

```
config :my_app, :task_impl, Task
```

and the `test.exs` to use `TaskStub` module instead

```
config :my_app, :task_impl, TaskStub
```

where the `TaskStub` might look like:

```
defmodule TaskStub do
  def async(_), do: :ok
end
```

---

One might also refer to [`Mox`](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html) documentation for the inspiration.